# Vimeo API Error 708

Tags: php, vimeo

using Vimeo API to upload a video (mp4) to my Vimeo account. Uinsg the vimeo.php file with a little modification (objects were used when they should have been arrays) I am calling

```
$video_id = $vimeo->upload
```

I am able to trace the getQuota, getTicket, verifyChunks but it fails on:

```
$this->call('vimeo.videos.upload.complete', array('ticket_id' => $ticket, 'filename' => $file_name));
```

With the following error:

```
stdClass Object(
[generated_in] => 1.0675
[stat] => fail
[err] => stdClass Object
    (
        [code] => 708
        [expl] => The file could not be saved. Try again.
        [msg] => File error
    ))
```

Any help?

Comment: Not sure if this thread will help you: http://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:68596

Comment: If you send ticket information to Vimeo, they can help track down exactly what might be happening.

Answer (score 0):

If it can be of any help, I had the exact same error and switching from **endpoint_secure** to **endpoint** resolved the issue from the upload form.

Comment: This bug was fixed months ago, if you are still seeing it please contact vimeo!