# Vimeo Upload Complete returns 708 File Error (python)

Tags: python, file-upload, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to build a little python script to compile and upload videos to vimeo. really about 9/10 the way there. 
it's authorizing, checking upload quota, getting an upload ticket, uploading via streaming, checking the chunk size. all of these return just fine. but when i try to call upload complete, it returns with

```
('complete upload response', '{"generated_in":"2.4796","stat":"fail","err":
{"code":"708","expl":"The file could not be saved. Try again.","msg":"File error"}}\n')
```

this is the code that loads the video file into binary text. this is what's loading into the html header on upload:

```
def load_video_to_bytes(self, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
        byte = f.read()
    return byte
```

the upload call

```
def call_upload_file(self, session, ticket_info, file, file_size):
    session.headers['Content-Type'] = 'video/mp4'
    session.headers['Content-Length'] = file_size
    response = session.put(ticket_info['endpoint_secure'], data=file)
    return response
```

where session is an rauth session
then the call to complete the upload

```
def call_upload_complete(self, session, ticket_id, filename):
    params = {'method': 'vimeo.videos.upload.complete',
              'oauth_token': session.access_token,
              'ticket_id': ticket_id,
              'filename': filename}
    response = self.execute_method(session, params)
    return response
```

here's all of the code in a gist
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7285498

is the binary data not loading right?

thanks,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265951/vimeo-api-error-708

Comment: Thanks Tim. I did try switching to the regular endpoint, but it didn't do anything different.

Comment: Thinking about this some more, I guess possible that my video sample isn't in the right format for Vimeo. The one I uploaded was crunched and converted with avconv. I'll try this with a known, native mp4 and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of troubleshooting chunk errors.

First you should make sure Vimeo isn't having any problems with your video, try manually uploading an example on site. If uploading on site works, the API should work. If it doesn't work let Vimeo know. I haven't encountered any times where a video was rejected during the upload so I doubt this is the problem.

Second you should ask vimeo how much of your upload was successful. The verify step of the upload flow (https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload#streaming-step4) allows you to ask just that. If you don't upload the video in order, or bytes were dropped, you might see the chunk error.